# Can we work with another company while in 60 day WARN period

Tags: california, immigration

My employer company A laid off some of the employees including me and I have 60 day notification period in which I am getting paid. I have another offer to start for company B before the end of the notification period. Is it required for me to notify my employer A before I start with company B. I'm employed as H1B worker will there be any legal repercussions for it?
I guess it will show in tax records that I got salary from company A and company B. How does one company know if I am employed in other company?

Comment: If Company A is paying you for the 60 days, they might suspect *something* if you are not at work, and stop paying you. Unless you want to cheat Company A, you could be up front with them, and ask if they need you at all (since they are laying you off).